# Cannot create a virtual environment with a specific version of Python in ubuntu with virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtual-environment, filenotfounderror

I am trying to create a virtual enviroment in my ubuntu OS using virtualenv

The command I am using is

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.8.13 py3.8.13_env
```

The error shown is

```
FileNotFoundError:[Errno 2]No such file or directory:'/usr/bin/python3.8.13'
```

I have tried several other python versions but I get the same error

Comment: So do you have the file `/usr/bin/python3.8.13`?

Comment: Try mentioning the full path instead of starting from /usr/..

Comment: @Suvidha This is Linux, `/usr/bin/` is a full path.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what versions of Python you have by:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python*
```

If you don't provide one then virtualenv will use a default of /usr/bin/python3. On Ubuntu this will be a symlink to a specific version. e.g.

```
/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10
```

So just calling virtualenv like:

```
virtualenv py3.10_venv
```

Would create a virtualenv called "py3.10_venv" (a folder) **in your current working directory**, using Python 3.10 in this example.

If you have other versions (shown by the ls command above) then you can use those specifically as you are trying to do in your question above.